# Amazon linux 2 - two kernels enabled

Tags: linux, kernel, upgrade

I recently upgraded kernel on one of the servers and I have two kernels enabled after reboot:

```
#  amazon-linux-extras |grep kernel
 _  kernel-5.4               available    [ =stable ]
55  kernel-5.10=latest       enabled      [ =stable ]
62  kernel-5.15=latest       enabled      [ =stable ]

# uname -r
5.15.137-91.144.amzn2.x86_64
```

It's not the same on other servers:

```
# amazon-linux-extras |grep kernel
  _  kernel-5.4               available    [ =stable ]
 55  kernel-5.10              available    [ =stable ]
 62  kernel-5.15=latest       enabled      [ =stable ]
```

Should I be worried? Everything seems to be working fine so far.

Best Regards,
Mihai R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having multiple kernels enabled after an upgrade is not unusual and might not necessarily be a cause for concern. However, it's always good to ensure the system's stability and check if the latest kernel upgrade didn't introduce any issues. Also check Boot Configuration.